# XSLT 2.0, Checking for the existence of specific node at specific position

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an XML with several `<MT>` elements like the ones below

```
<GSP>
<RES>
<R>
<MT N="Authors" V="McKee, D.W.; General Electric Co., Schenectady, NY (USA). Corporate Research and Development Dept"/>
<MT N="English-Title" V="Advanced gas-cooled nuclear reactor materials evaluation and development program: corrosion behavior of experimental alloys in controlled-purity helium at temperatures in the 750 to 1050&lt;sup&gt;0&lt;/sup&gt;C range"/>
<MT N="Title" V="Ni-20Cr + Al, Ti, Si, Nb and/or Y"/>
</R>
</RES>
</GSP>
```

I want to check if there is an element with `@N='Title'` immediately after `@N='English-Title'`. I don't want to use the `<MT>` element with `@N='Title'`, if it appears anywhere else.

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
//MT[@N='Title'][preceding-sibling::MT[1][@N='English-Title']]
```

will *select* those nodes. It selects among *all* `MT` elements which have an `N` attribute with the contents "Title", the ones which the preceding `MT` sibling contains an `N` attribute with the contents "English Title".

You can use it inside an XSLT attribute that accepts absolute XPath expressions and print it to the result tree, save it in a variable, etc.

Comment: +1 You could also use: `//MT[@N='English-Title']/following-sibling::MT[1][@N='Title']`